# Правильно ли поставлены знаки препинания? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

..., то вовсю начинают появляться личности, не упускающие возможности обидеть хрупкую душу распускающегося цветка.

Comment: Это домашнее задание?

Comment: Нет, не домашнее задание.

Comment: "В глазах идущего тебе навстречу" воспринималось бы более однозначно как "его" глаза; "в глазах [обращённых] навстречу идущему тебе есть свет" - это уже было бы о глазах, обращённых на идущего (не обязательно своих глаз). Поэтому есть смысл пересмотреть и порядок слов.

Answer (score 1):

1) ...то вовсю начинают появляться личности, не упускающие возможность обидеть хрупкую душу распускающегося цветка.

Замена падежа сделана для устранения неясности (единственное, а не множественное число сущ. "возможность").

2) Если в глазах навстречу тебе идущего  есть свет, то никто .

Инверсия:  идущий навстречу тебе, "идущий" имеет предметное значение  существительного.

Comment: Думаю, в первом предложении фраза "не упускающие возможности" предполагает, что слово "возможности" стоит в родительном падеже единственного числа. Так требуется писать, когда главное слово словосочетания выражено глаголом с частицей "не", а управляемое(зависимое) слово обозначает какое-то абстрактное понятие - в данном случае "возможность"

Comment: Фраза, может быть, предполагает,  но  мн. число поддерживается  словом "не упускающие". Вы послушайте, как звучит предложение, на слух воспринимается как форма множественного числа - "возможности".

Answer (score 0):

> правильно ли поставлены знаки препинания?

Знаки-то препинания поставлены правильно. Только...

*Если в глазах на встречу идущего тебе…* (?)

По-моему, надо или так:

*Если в глазах **навстречу** идущего тебе…*

или так:

*Если в глазах на встречу идущего **к** тебе…*